# Video background in PHP for index page

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying for a video background on my index page which works fine on HTML page but doesn't work on PHP.

```
<div class="header-container"> <div class = "video-container"> <video preload = "true" autoplay = "autoplay" loop= "loop" volume = "0" poster = "pic.jpg"> <source src = "mp4/fa.mp4" type="video/mp4" > </video> </div> </div>
```

```
.header-container { width:100%; height: 900px; border-left: none; border-right: none; position: relative; padding: 20px; } 

.video-container { position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0%; height: 100%; width: 100%; overflow: hidden; } 

video { position: absolute; z-index: -1; opacity: 0.78; width: 100%; }
```

I want to make it work on php.

I am not able to figure out why it isn't playing on localhost, although it displays the text content perfectly. Only video playback is not visible.

Comment: _"works fine on html page but doesnt work on php"_ Any error messages?  Does the video simply not play? Does it crash? Add some more information

Comment: PHP is server side language that return html, so you have other problem.

Comment: 1) have no spaces in HTML around `=`s. 2) "doesn't work" is not a proper problem statement.

Comment: Perhaps you could put the PHP code on here so we can see. It might be something simple like a syntax error.

Comment: hi, what i have done is simply renamed the .html to .php

Comment: Yes  marekful You were right. removing of spaces worked out. Its playing cool now... thanks... Cheers to StackOverflow! superb!!!

Comment: Where is PHP codes in your sample code?